# URI PHP. Как сделать чтобы ссылка была другой

Tags: php, url

Здравствуйте, у меня имеется такой PHP код в **index.php**

```
<?php

if  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') $page = 'home';
else {
  $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
  if (!preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{2,15}$/', $page)) exit('ERROR URL');
}
session_start();

if (file_exists('r/'.$page.'.php')) include 'r/'.$page.'.php';
else exit ('404');
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Также в папке **/r/** имеется **russian.php**. И ссылка по которой перейти можно это **site.ru/russian**.
Вопрос таков, как мне сделать так чтобы ссылка была не **site.ru/russian** а именно **site.ru/r/russian**?